# Disable ip v6 in docker container

Tags: docker, ipv6

I have ipv6 enabled on docker host but there is one particular container where ipv6 is causing issues. Is there a way to launch a container without ipv6 support, either through command line argument or dockerfile directive?

Comment: here is a Dockerfile and .sh on how to enable IPV6 in a container, I guess you can do the reverse easily https://github.com/DominicBoettger/docker-ipv6

Comment: Actually, P(you can't do it|you want to do something in Docker) > 90%.

Comment: All you really have to do is disable it in your network adapter's settings. Docker won't use it if it isn't available.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't: `--ipv6` is a daemon-wide flag that cannot be overridden on a per-container basis.

Answer (score 27):

Two options:

1. Run docker with `--dns-opt='options single-request'`.  See [docs](https://docs.docker.com/network/#dns-services)
2. Run with `--sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1`.  See discussion [here](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/20569)

Comment: It's impossible to say whether either of these will solve the user's problem, because he never bothered to say what the problem was.

Comment: i added --dns-opt='...' to /lib/systemd/system/docker.service, and it works fine, thanks ! Now when i do `curl https://ifconfig.co/ip` it works, i was getting `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ifconfig.co`

Comment: Using `--dns-opt='options single-request'` leads to `options options single-request` in /etc/resolv.conf on docker 20.10.17. I had to use `--dns-opt='single-request'` instead

Comment: So the `dns-opt` depends on the operating system for a valid `resolv.conf` configuration, actually.

Answer (score 10):

Its kind of tricky. I just had the same issue what I did was to run the container with the ip:

```
docker run --name YourDockerContainer -p 192.168.99.100:80:80
```

This will start the container on this ip:  `192.168.99.100`.

Comment: Great solution! I was having an issue with mysql not starting with this error `Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp6 [::]:3306: socket: address family not supported by protocol.` and setting the port to 0.0.0.0:3306 worked!

Comment: Taking this answer as a basis, I found that using `-p 0.0.0.0:80:80` does IPV4 mapping only, like doing `-p 80:80` but disabling IPV6 mapping. Then `docker ps` gives `0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp` in PORTS column instead of `0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, :::80->80/tcp` which has IPV6 mapping.

Answer (score 8):

The way I think of disabling ipv6 with Docker is by creating a network without ipv6.

For example

```
docker network create --ipv6=false disable_ipv6
```

And runs with:

```
docker run --network disable_ipv6
docker build --network disable_ipv6
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking to disable IPv6 from within a Linux Docker image, this seems to work even when the file system is read-only.

```
sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
sysctl net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
```

These commands are privileged; run with `sudo` if you are not `root`.

Comment: @ATorras Can you please clarify the rationale for your edit? The commands work without the `=1` for me.

Comment: your command was correct, but you'll need to assign a value in order to update the kernel parameter.

Comment: `sysctl: error setting key 'net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6': Read-only file system`

Answer (score 1):

**Worked for me:**

```
docker run -d -i -t  --name django_1.0 --sysctl 
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1 -p 192.168.20.148:8000:8000/tcp -p 
192.168.20.148:8000:8000/udp -p 192.168.20.148:3000:3000/tcp -p 
192.168.20.148:3000:3000/udp IMAGE_NAME

root:~# netstat -tlp | grep -i docker

tcp  0  0 ip-192-168-20-148.:8000 *:*    LISTEN      4598/docker-proxy

tcp  0  0 ip-192-168-20-148.:3000 *:*    LISTEN      4642/docker-proxy
```

Answer (score -2):

To disable ipv6, run docker container with:

-e "extra_params=--o:net.proto=IPv4"

Tested on Ubuntu 20.04, collabora office container.

UPDATE:
But this did not worked runing pgadmin container, so added extra line:

-e "PGADMIN_LISTEN_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0" \

Comment: The `-e` is for environment variables, both solutions you provided *only* apply to applications within the Docker container and are not solutions for Docker containers in general (which was the questions purpose).